# Homology Class of Möbius Band attached to the Torus via the map $f_{m,n}:\partial M=S^1\to S^1\times S^1, z\mapsto (z^m,z^n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am currently trying to solve the following problem:

Let $f_{m,n}:\partial M=S^1\to S^1\times S^1=:T, z\mapsto (z^m,z^n)$ be the map via which we attach the Möbius strip $M$ to the torus $T$ to obtain $X_{m,n}:=M\cup_{f_{m,n}}T$ where $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and we consider $S^1$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{C}$.

Find the homology groups of $X_{m,n}$.

I thought of solving it with an exact sequence and relative homology, so something like this

\begin{equation*}
...\to C_2(T)\to C_2(X_{m,n})\to C_2(X_{m,n}/ T)\to C_1(T)\to C_1(X_{m,n})\to C_1(X_{m,n}/ T)\to ...
\end{equation*}

My first question is whether my idea that $X_{m,n}/T\simeq \mathbb{R}P^2$ is correct since we contract $T$ to a point, so the boundary of $M$ which is attached to it will contract to a point as well and we know that $M/\partial M\simeq \mathbb{R}P^2$?

The second question concerns the maps between the cell complexes:

Is the map $C_i(T)\to C_i(X_{m,n})$ the one induced by inclusion or can I use the map $f_{m,n}$ here somehow?

How do I find the map $C_i(X_{m,n}/T)\to C_{i-1}(T)$? I thought that here I could use $f_{m,n}$ together with the projection $X_{m,n}\to X_{m,n}/T$ somehow but I cannot figure out a way how to.
I think that $\deg(f_{m,n})=m\cdot n$, so one map would simply be sending the generator of one group to $m\cdot n$-times the generators of the other.

And now in detail if someone could calculate the missing maps and homology groups (even if they have another approach). Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you know about the Mayer-Vietoris sequence?

Comment: @ronno Yes, I do. I thought about applying it with $A=$image of the torus with an added neighborhood in $M$ and $B=$ image of $M$ again with an added neighborhood. Now my problem here is that I cannot picture what $A\cap B$ looks like. I feel like it could be homotopic to $\bigvee_{i=1}^{lcm(m,n)}S^1$ but I don't know.

Comment: Let the image of $\partial M$ in $T$ be $C \cong S^1$. If you pick a neighborhood of $\partial M$ of the form $\partial M \times [0,1]$ and a neighborhood $U$ of $C$ that retracts to $C$ then the intersection is the mapping cylinder of $\partial M \to U$, which deformation retracts to $U$, and then to $C$.

Comment: @ronno Thanks!  I now get that the homology groups are $H_0(X_{m,n})=\mathbb{Z}, H_1(X_{m,n})=\mathbb{Z}_m\oplus\mathbb{Z}_n, H_i(X_{m,n})=0\forall i\geq 2$ by exactness. Hope that's correct.

Comment: Actually with what I said the neighborhood of $M$ would not retract to $M$, added a full and more detailed answer.

Comment: @Olivia: I know an answer was already posted, but a few comments on your question. First, when you look at the LES for a pair $(X,A)$, the map $H_i(A) \to H_i(X)$ is indeed induced by the inclusion $A \to X$, so the answer is yes for that. Second, it doesn't quite make sense to talk about the degree of the map $f = f_{m,n}: S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1$ ('degree' is usually used to discuss the induced map on top-rank homology) but you can compute that on $H_1$, $f_*$ sends $1$ to $(m,n)$ (and is 0 in degree 2, since $H_2(S^1) = 0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a neighborhood of $\partial M$ in $M$ of the form $\partial M \times [0,1]$ (with $\partial M $ being identified with $\partial M \times 0$). Write $X = \hat{T} \cup \hat{M}$ where $\hat{T}$ is the image of $T \cup (\partial M \times [0,2/3))$ and $\hat{M}$ is the image of $M \setminus (\partial M \times [0,1/3]) \simeq M$. Then $\hat{T} \cap \hat{M} = \partial M \times (1/3, 2/3)$.
Note that $\hat{T}$ is the (open) mapping cylinder and hence deformation retracts to $T$ (by contracting $[0,2/3)$ to $0$).

Now the corresponding (reduced) Mayer-Vietoris sequence is of the form:
$$\dots \to H_3(X) \to H_2(\partial M) \to H_2(T) \oplus H_2(M) \to H_2(X) \to H_1(\partial M) \to H_1(T) \oplus H_1(M) \to H_1(X) \to 0$$
Since $H_2(\partial M)$ and higher terms coming from $T$, $M$ and $\partial M$ are all $0$, $H_i(X) = 0$ for $i > 2$. The map $H_1(\partial M) \to H_1(T) \oplus H_1(M)$, $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}^3$ is given by $(m, n, 2)$. Since this is injective and $H_2(\partial M) = H_2(M) = 0$, $H_2(X) \cong H_2(T) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. On the other side $H_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}^3/\mathbb{Z}\langle(m,n,2)\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}^2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/\gcd(m,n,2)$. Since $X$ is connected, $H_0(X) = \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I think your M-V sequence is going in the wrong direction, but since you also switched the positions of $\partial M$ and $X$ in the sequence you still got the right answer. It should be $\cdots \to H_n(\partial M) \to H_n(T) \oplus H_n(M) \to H_n(X) \to H_{n-1}(\partial M) \to \cdots$. Also I think you mean to say that $\hat{T}$ is what deformation retracts to $T$, not $\hat{M}$.

Comment: @Kamills Thanks for the corrections, I initially wrote everything in cohomology and then fixed it badly :(